# Where to put keyboard show event handler so it fires immediately?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, keyboard, ionic-framework

I'm developing an hybrid application with cordova and angularJS. 
 I'm trying to move two input texts upwards when a virtual keyboard appears using the ionic keyboard plugin.
 I wrote a code that moves the input texts upwards when the keyboard opens BUT has to wait for an other action to do it.
 For example, the input does only move after the user has put focus on the input text (so keyboards appears) AND has typed the first letter... 
 My question is, where should I put my code so that it triggers immediately ? Or what should I change in it so that it works ?

Here is the beginning of my app.js file,

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova', 'jrCrop'])

.run(function($rootScope){
                 $rootScope.keyboardIsVisible = false;
                 $rootScope.keyboardIsNotVisible = true;
                 window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);
                 function keyboardShowHandler(keyboardParameters){
                                                      $rootScope.keyboardIsVisible = true;
                                                      $rootScope.keyboardIsNotVisible = false;
                                                  };
                 window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);
                 function keyboardHideHandler(keyboardParameters){
                                                      $rootScope.keyboardIsVisible = false;
                                                      $rootScope.keyboardIsNotVisible = true;
                                                  };
                 })
```

my template,

```
  <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl" ng-class="{ 'connexion-form-keyboard-open': keyboardIsVisible, 'connexion-form': !keyboardIsVisible }" ng-model-onblur>
  <form role="form" id="form" novalidate>
    <input value="{{info.mail}}" ng-model="info.mail" type="text" placeholder="Mail"
    onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Mail'" required/>
    <div id="sep"></div>
    <input value="{{info.passwd}}" ng-model="info.passwd" type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Mot de passe'" required/>
  </form>
  </div>
```

The css linked to it,

```
.connexion-form-keyboard-open {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 71%;
}

.connexion-form {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 50%;
}
```

Comment: What does "has to wait for another action mean?" Can you clarify the actual behaviour more?

Comment: When the keyboard opens, the value of keyboardIsVisible only changes when the user has written the first letter.
When the keyboard closes, the value only changes when the user tries to send the form.
It seems to me that the event is not taken into account directly, the user has to do something else before the value of keyboardIsVisible changes.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that changes to your $rootScope.KeyboardIsVisible is not propagated to the child scope until you start typing in the input box, triggering an $apply/$digest.

Why don't you try broadcasting an event to your scope?

In your keyboardShowHandler():

`$rootScope.$broadcast("keyboardOpenEvent");`

And in your controller:

`$scope.$on("keyboardOpenEvent",function () {$scope.KeyboardIsVisible = true;})`

Comment: I understand the delay introduced by $rootScope.
It then seems to me that broadcasting an event with $rootScope will not shortcut the $rootScope !
I tested and the delay is still there.
Maybe is there a way to handle the event directly in the controller ? (creates code-redundancy if multiple templates are to use the event handler but might work...)

Comment: Are you saying the event is being broadcasted properly, but it's not received right away in your $scope? Did you debug the timestamps for that? That $scope.$on here is indeed handling the event directly in the controller. I'm interested to know where the delay happens, if it's in broadcasting, $scope.$on, or angular ng-class?

Comment: Yes, that is what I think happens.
For the timestamps, the console displays the right time. I don't know what else to check ?
I launched a debug and it appears that the broadcast line is reached properly but that the $scope.$on is not directly taken into account.